# App opens to specific ViewController inside Navigation Controller

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to have my app open to a specific ViewController that is deeply embedded in a Navigation Controller, but isn't the RootViewController. I have tried in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions adding:

```
  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavViewController")
  self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But this goes to the root view controller. I tried changing this line to:

```
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController")
```

and this **does** open to the correct viewcontroller but then there is no Navigation Bar on the top which is needed to navigate in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `rootViewController` from the `AppDelegate` then here is the code:

```
let rootViewController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let notificationVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as! NotificationVC
rootViewController.pushViewController(notificationVC, animated: false)
```

Now, it will have the `navigationBar`. Let me know, if you still face the issue. thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Now I'm trying to do a similar thing from a View Controller that isn't embedded in the Navigation Controller. Any ideas?

Comment: @bdc You just want to display or want to push / pop?

Comment: Either way. I suppose push/pop unless that's more complicated.

Comment: If you want to push / pop then you need to assign `UINavigationController` programmatically. Else you can directly load any `UIViewController` by `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method!.

Comment: Right, but if I use  `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to jump to a View Controller that's embedded inside a Navigation Controller (but it's not the root VC), there's no navigation bar. The same thing happens if I use a segue too. Basically I have view controllers  A [B C D]  and [B C D] are in a Navigation Controller with B as the root. I want to go from A to C.

Comment: If you are not using the `UINavigationController` as a rootViewController then you will not get the `UINavigationBar` for sure becaz it inherits from it!

Comment: View Controller A is not embedded inside a Navigation Controller. B->C->D are (B has a UINaviagtionController behind it and is the root). If I use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier from A to C, C doesn't have a Navigation Bar. If I normally go from A to B to C then it does. Is there a way to jump from outside the NavigationController to View Controller C and also have a NavBar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Objective-C version to open a specific `UIViewController` deeply embedded inside a `UINavigationController` (which is not the rootController).

If we take @bdc example in comments and we want to open `UIViewController` D:

- A : rootViewController
- N : navigationController
- B, C, D : UIViewControllers embedded in N
- A -> N[B C D]

---

Set `storyboardId` in InterfaceBuilder for every `UIViewController` or `UINavigationController` in the hierarchy through D.

In AppDelegate, the code is straight forward. You just have to instantiate everything, and use your `UINavigationController` to push every `UIViewController` in your hierarchy.

```
// Instanciate from storyboard with identifiers

UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * N = (UINavigationController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"N"];
UIViewController* B = (UIViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
UIViewController* C = (UIViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
UIViewController* D = (UIViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"D"];

// Set up the views hierarchy

self.window.rootViewController = N;
[N pushViewController:B animated:NO];
[N pushViewController:C animated:NO];
[N pushViewController:D animated:YES];
    
    
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Hope this will help.